# Count function in HQL causing null results?

Tags: hibernate, count, hql, aggregate-functions

I have the following HQL query that is attempting to return 2 object instances as well as an aggregate count based upon a 3rd object instance.

```
SELECT
    client,
    clientCampaign,
    count( formData )
FROM
    FormData as formData
    JOIN formData.deliveryResults as deliveryResults
    JOIN formData.leadForm as leadForm
    JOIN leadForm.campaignForms as campaignForms
    JOIN campaignForms.clientCampaignForms.clientCampaign as clientCampaign
    JOIN clientCampaign.client as client
WHERE
    client.id = ?
GROUP BY
    client.id, clientCampaign.id
```

The results always return with the clientCampaign instance being null.  However, if I remove the count( formData ) line from the SELECT clause, the clientCampaign instance is no longer null.  I have checked the data set and there are 5 total formData records ... 3 for one clientCampaign and 2 for another.  So, I believe this query should be returning 2 results, both with non-null clientCampaign instances.

Can anybody tell if there is something obvious I am missing here?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you post your object mappings? It's hard to say without them but it feels (judging by names) that you're walking up the hierarchy (from collection to owner) instead of down, which is somewhat unnatural using Hibernate.
2. `JOIN formData.deliveryResults as deliveryResults` is unnecessary (it's not used anywhere). Most other joins may be unnecessary as well - for "to-one" associations you can write properties using nested dot notation without explicit joins.
3. Your `GROUP BY` clause only lists IDs whereas you're selecting full entities (client and clientCampaign). That's not going to work - you have to [explicitly list fields to group by](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping).

Depending on your mappings, you may be able to rewrite this query using parent-to-child joins; you may than be able to use [`size()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) function on your `deliveryResults` collection without need for `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Because of the way the mappings are defined at this point, I am in affect going from collection to owner and can't do anything about it without a lot of hassle.

Regarding point 2, yes, there is some clean up that can be done on the from clause.  I have been working and reworking this query and there was apparently some left over crud.

Could you explain your 3rd point.  I am pretty new to hibernate and I am not sure I am following what you are saying / suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Well, can you post your mappings (edit your question and add them)? Without that it's hard to say anything specific. I can't imagine, though, why it would be impossible to go from owner to collection without changing mappings - collection is ALWAYS accessible. Re: 3rd point - if your `client` has, say, a `name` property, it's added to `select` clause (implicitly as you're selecting the entire client) but it's not in your `group by` clause, causing the actual SQL query to be wrong (count is aggregated by ids only, wrong rows are picked up)

Answer (score 0):

Before other comment, I like the way you present your HQL request at first, with each JOIN on its own line. It is very readable. I suggest you refactor the clientCampaign the same way, even if you don't use the aliases...  This might also change some results (who knows what code could be triggered in the inners of Hibernate with your original request !?).

You request seem to move between tables going up and down (judging from names, if they end with an 's' or not). It is a bit hard to read. I would probably be easier for you and for us to switch to a single order (for example going down, starting from leadForm). In particular, we would detect other "joins" going up, and examine them more carefully (I'm suspicious at `clientCampaignForms.clientCampaign`...)